# connmand add and removing routes

Tags: linux, networking, connman

I have a connman daemon running on arm busybox linux with connman managing its networking.

Also I have ipsec tunnel to a private network.

My problem is connman keeping deleting and add routings of its own.

```
Jan  5 22:21:24 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {del} route 0.0.0.0 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:21:24 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:21:55 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {add} route 10.131.12.9 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:21:55 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {add} route 10.131.22.9 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:21:55 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {add} route 8.8.8.8 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:22:09 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {del} route 10.131.12.9 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:22:09 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {del} route 10.131.22.9 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:22:09 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {del} route 8.8.8.8 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:22:09 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {del} route 0.0.0.0 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jan  5 22:22:09 klk-lpbs-061316 daemon.info connmand[925]: eth0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 10.16.100.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
```

The funny part is 10.131.12.9 and 10.131.22.9, should be route via tunnel.

```
10.131.12.0/28 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0  src 15.1.0.1 
10.131.22.0/28 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0  src 15.2.0.1
```

Why does connman adds the routes as below and removes it at times?

```
10.131.12.0/28 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0  src 15.1.0.1 
10.131.12.9 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0 
10.131.22.0/28 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0  src 15.2.0.1 
10.131.22.9 via 10.16.100.1 dev eth0
```

How do i prevent connman from add the above routes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to proxy arp which is set on your routing device

Comment: can u explain in more detail about this?